# How to create a table of correlation between variables in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, correlation

I have a table of variables and i would like to perform a correlation analysis between each column.
I use this code to get a correlation for individually.

```py
df['A'].corr(df['B'])
```

I want to be able to loop this to create a different table.
For example, the original table is

```
        A   B   C
Site1   4   1   8
Site2   8   5   4
Site3   3   3   2
Site4   8   6   5
Site5   9   9   8
```

And the table i want to get is

```
     A     B     C
A    1    0.87  0.33
B   0.87   1    0.2
C   0.33  0.2    1
```

How do I create this loop?

Comment: you can use the method `corr` on the full dataframe instead of on series, try `df.corr()`

Comment: [Check the documentation!](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html)

Comment: how about `df.corr()`?

Comment: Just wanted to add: In pandas, a loop is almost never the best way to do things

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I didnt know I could do it for the full table.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this:

```
import pandas as pd
a = [4,8,3,8,9]
b = [1,5,3,6,9]
c = [8,4,2,5,8]
d = {'A': a, 'B': b, 'C':c}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.corr()
```